# Dropbox > git commit

Tags: git, github, dropbox

Is there anything I can do to automatically commit dropbox changes to github? (vice versa would be nice too but optional)

I have tried "Zapier" however it didn't seem to want to work

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have it commit whenever a dropbox change happens 

not sure what you mean by use case

Comment: Please see answer. The meaning of each commit is quite important in Git.

Answer (score 6):

This is particularly difficult to do cleanly due to the fundamental differences in the way that Git and Dropbox are intended to be used. Lets compare Git with Dropbox:

Dropbox is a tool for seamlessly syncing a folder between several different users in near real time. Dropbox quickly transmits small, meaningless (though important) deltas of the files. Git is (amongst several other things) a tool for building a clean and understandable revision history of a folder made up from meaningful deltas of the files, with a short message describing that meaning. In the ideal world, you would want several Dropbox deltas to be included in one commit. Also, you want to be able to select which of your changes to commit into the Git repo

You could write some hacky scripts to `git add` and `git commit` with a randomized message whenever the files in Dropbox change, but instead I would recommend seriously reconsidering what you expect the repo to look like, and whether it is actually a good idea.

You could also set a commit message in a bash variable, then every second you could add every small Dropbox delta, then rebase and force push to Github. This would be good for people who like to keep a clear git history/repo. Force pushing to GitHub has its own problems though, such as people pulling the force-pushed commit getting duplicate commits.

I recommend only doing a commit when you make a useful set of changes (or have something WIP that you want keps), and then describing them with a good message and committing them manually. If you don't care about the commit messages or the content of each commit, then git might not be the right scm for you to use.